# How to keep the column width in an HTML table equal for all columns based on the widest column

Tags: html, html-table, column-width

I see a lot of questions regarding column width, but I was not able to find an answer for a scenario exactly like mine.

Here is my table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Title goes here</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td class="right">B</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">C</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td class="right">G</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>H</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="center">I</td>
        <td rowspan="2" class="right">J</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>K</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>M</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="right">N</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="center">O</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
<style>
    table 
    {
        table-layout: fixed;

    }

    table, td 
    {
        border: 1px solid;
    }

    .right 
    {
        text-align:right;
        vertical-align:bottom;
    }
    .center 
    {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

What I want to achieve is all five columns to have the same width based on the widest one. The idea is that I don't know how big the title will be. I know that I could set a fixed width for the table (e.g. 200px or 100%), but I don't want to do that. I want both the width of the columns and the width of the table to expand as the title expands. And as you can see the title spans three columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m afraid this cannot be done in HTML, even with the help of CSS. You need some scripting too: a script that processes the table after the browser has formatted it, finds out the widest column, and sets all columns to that width. Assuming your `table` element has `id=t`, the following pure JavaScript code does the job:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
var tbl = document.getElementById("t");
var row = tbl.rows[0];
var maxWidth = 1;
for ( var i = 0; i < row.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
  var width = row.childNodes[i].offsetWidth;
  if(width > maxWidth) { maxWidth = width; } 
  }
for ( var i = 0; i < row.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
  row.childNodes[i].style.width = maxWidth + "px"; 
  }
}
</script>
```